My laptop has been stuck at this for almost 2 hours while upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Today I got a notification from the software updater for Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. I clicked the upgrade’ now button. It started without an issue, but after a while; it got stuck at this and remains still. What to do now?

Reboot do a fresh install and restore data from back up would be my suggestion.

I rebooted it and it is now stuck at boot. Fresh installation would be the best option for me at this point, I guess.

Same thing happened to me. Haven't rebooted yet.

For me, the issue was that there was a dialog open asking me about the current Grub config. It was open on another monitor, which wasn't on.
So check for this dialog before rebooting.
